# Mat-input formatted with dollar sign

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I format a mat input text box to show the dollar sign symbol ? I have an example of what I am currently using but I am not sure how to place the dollar sign symbol inside of the input. Can someone please provide a possible solution for what I'm trying to do.

html

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        type="number"
        aria-labelledby="breakfast"
        [formControl]="bfastamountCtrl"
        [value]="bfastamountCtrl.value | number: '1.2-2'"
        formControlName="breakfast"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>      
</div>
</div>
```

ts

```
bfastamountCtrl = new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur'});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can prepend a dollar sign to your value with a function like:

```
addDollarSign(text: string) {
  return '$ ' + text
}
```

then

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        type="number"
        aria-labelledby="breakfast"
        [formControl]="bfastamountCtrl"
        [value]="addDollarSign(bfastamountCtrl.value) | number: '1.2-2'"
        formControlName="breakfast"
      />
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>      
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I am getting compile errors for this.

Comment: I just noticed I put the function around the whole pipe and value, I've updated it to just go around the value.